# Как правильно поддерживать соединение сервер-клиент

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте разработчики! Есть сокет сервер. Вот клиент авторизовался на сервере, соединение установлено. Но теперь как убедиться что при вызове какого-то метода на сервере его вызвал именно тот же клиент? На ум приходит только проверять пароль пользователя каждый вызов метода.

Comment: Не совсем понятна используемая вами модель угроз. От кого/чего вы хотите защититься? Почему вы думаете, что в пределах установленного соединения вызвать может кто-то, не являющийся «тем же клиентом»?

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать эту тему. Я хочу защититься от так называемой атаки посредника. Разве этот посредник не сможет вклиниться в соединение и вызвать какой-то другой метод?

Comment: Посредник точно так же сможет перехватить передаваемый пароль, так что проверка пароля тут уже не поможет. В таком случае берите TLS и делайте шифрование

Comment: Когда подключается клиент, на сервере хранится сокет соединения с этим клиентом. Вы хотите сказать, что это уже серверная логика и взломать её можно только взломав сервер?
Ну а что если по каналу связи вклинится MitM ещё до логики сервера (на пути от клиента к серверу).

Comment: Для защиты от MitM берите TLS и делайте шифрование